# Manipulate JSON object with non ASC-II characters?

Tags: python, json, ascii

I'm trying to make an API call to Google CSE from python and then manipulate the resulting object into a dictionary object that I can manipulate. I think this question is not duplicated because the issue here I believe is that there are non ASC-II characters which leads to the resulting object being of type 'NoneType' and the resulting json object 'null'. I've played with the options documented for json including "ensure_ascii=False", but haven't been successful. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**Code:**

```
import pprint, os, json
from googleapisclient.discovery import build
def search(searchkey,datekey,developkey,enginekey):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1",
    developerKey=developkey).cse().list(
    q=searchkey,dateRestrict=datekey, 
    cx=enginekey,        
    ).execute()
pprint.pprint(service)

mykey       = 'My_Private_Key'

myengine    = '009333857041890623793:z_drq9obxp0'

object2write    = search('narco','20170101-20170201',mykey,myengine)
type(object2write)

jsonAbder = json.dumps(object2write, ensure_ascii=False, allow_nan=False)
print(jsonAbder)
```

Comment: "because the issue here I believe is that there are non ASC-II characters which leads to the resulting object being of type 'NoneType' " Nope. JSON doesn't even work with ASCII, it works with UTF-8 (it happens to be equivalent to ASCII in the codepoints between 0-127).

Answer (score 0):

The proximal cause of your error is that your `search` function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement. Thus, it *implicitely* returns `None`, which gets encoded into JSON `null`. Your issue has nothing to do with character encodings.

Just add:

```
    return service
```

at the end of your function.